# Template with function pointer to usual function and member function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have **a function** which loads data from file, parse it and pass this data to another function called 'loader'. It **puts** this parsed **data into global variables or class members**:

```
class ParsedData;

template<typename Loader>
int load_file(std::string file_path, Loader loader) {
  ParsedData parsed_data;
  try {
    ParsedData parsed_data = parse_file(file_path);
    return loader(parsed_data);
  } catch(...) {
    // doing some stuff, handling exceptions and so on
    return 1;
  }
}
```

And somewhere I have defined 2 different loaders:

```
int loader();
int MyClass::loader();
```

Then I want to use it:

```
int load() {
  load_file("global_options.txt", loader);
}

int MyClass::load() {
  load_file("instance_options.txt", loader);
}

int main() {
  load(); // load global options
  MyClass my_class_instance;
  my_class_instance.load(); // load instance options
}
```

The template instantiation is ok, but the **syntax of calling** `loader` **is different**. It's quite clear I've got a compilation error: `must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function`. I should have written somewhere in `load_file`:

```
return my_class_instance_ptr->*loader(parsed_data);
```

Is it possible to bypass this restriction or should I pass a pointer to instance to `load_file` and write a static function wrapper for this loader?

PS: I found out ways to fulfil this task but all the solutions seem to be clumsy. I think we can't cope with it without static functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your instance to your member function:

```
int MyClass::load() {
  load_file("instance_options.txt", std::bind(this, &MyClass::loader));
}
```

If you can't use c++11 use `boost::bind`

Comment: How can I do this without using c++11 and boost?

Comment: @nirname You need to crate a new object that stores your instance as a member and overloads its `operator()` which will then invoke the `loader` member function of the stored instance :)

Comment: Is it possible to do with <functional> header?

Comment: I mean in versions earlier than c++11?

Comment: Obviously, it is not possible

Comment: @nirname Except reimplementing bind yourself i'm not aware of another way. That's basically why bind is one of the most used tool in boost (personally it is the first i needed) and why it was added to the c++ standard library.